# Displaying only selected checkboxes in a PHP form mailer.

Tags: php, html, email, forms

My PHP code for "mailhandler.php" seems to be showing all the checkboxes on my HTML site as checked when it arrives in my email. I want the user to only select the checkboxes they want, so only their selection shows up in my email.

HTML CODE FOR CHECKBOX:

```
< input type="checkbox" name="event1" value="Summer" />
```

HTML CODE FOR PHP MAILHANDLER:

```
$owner_email ='MYEMAIL';
$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
$subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['ticketnumber']!='nope'){     
    $messageBody .= '<p>Ticket Number: ' . $_POST['ticketnumber'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email List: ' . $_POST['elist'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['ticketnumber1']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Ticket Number: ' . $_POST['ticketnumber1'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}


if($_POST['event1']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Checked Photo 1 ' . $_POST['event1'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['event2']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Checked Photo 2 ' . $_POST['event2'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}


if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="event1" value="Summer" />
```

this is how you check if it was checked at the moment of submission:

```
if (isset($_POST['event1']) && $_POST['event1'] === 'Summer') {
  echo 'Checkbox event1 was checked';
} else {
  echo 'Checkbox event1 was not checked';
}
```

The rules are:

- if the checkbox was checked, the name of the checkbox will be a key in the $_POST super global and the checkbox value will be the value of the key (the default value if you don't give a value to the checkbox is "on" without the quotes)
- if the checkbox was NOT checked, there is nothing in the $_POST super global for that checkbox

There is a trick you can use if you want to always have a key corresponding to the checkbox and only check for the value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="event1" value="no" />
<input type="checkbox" name="event1" value="yes" />
```

In this case the "event1" will always be present in $_POST and you can only check the value.

Of course, you should never assume that the form will be submitted from your specific HTML form. The key might still be missing or have a different value than you expect if someone posts to your email handler using a custom HTML form or a tool like curl. This is why you should not use the $_POST super global directly, but use a method to access request that performs all these checks for you:

```
class Request
{
    public function post($key, $default = null)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
            return $_POST[$key];
        } else {
            return $default;
        }
    }
}

$request = new Request();
if ($request->post('event1') === 'Summer') {
    echo 'Checkbox event1 was checked';
} else {
    echo 'Checkbox event1 was not checked';
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but the code you have given once I put it in and test it I'm only receiving my "Ticket Number" nothing else.

Comment: I used this code and all I got was the ticket number am I missing something else that needs to be added to HTML or PHP?. <input type="checkbox" name="event1" value="Summer" />
this is how you check if it was checked at the moment of submission:

if (isset($_POST['event1']) && $_POST['event1'] === 'Summer') {
  echo 'Checkbox event1 was checked';
} else {
  echo 'Checkbox event1 was not checked';
}

Answer (score 0):

this will check if the value of 'Y'(yes=checked) is present in the database and echo it

```
<?php if ($something['*something*']=='Y') echo 'checked';  ?>
```